# Как в ToolBar добавить кнопку обновить

Tags: java, android

Использую `ToolBar` от Material design.

Нужно добавить в `Toolbar` кнопку обновить при нажатии на которую приходит `ProgressBar` и затем обновление завершается.
Как могу это все реализовать?

Поиск на англоязычных форумах и гитхабе результатов не дал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Создайте в ресурсах xml файл с меню
2. Добавьте его в тулбар
3. Повесьте на него слушатель нажатия
4. В слушателе совершите нужное действие - запуск задачи и отображение прогресса
5. По окончании задачи остановите прогресс

Comment: какой именно слушаетль будет уместен по теме?*

Comment: В зависимости от того как будете делать. Например onOptionsItemsSelected

Comment: все это от части я сделал но как прогрес бар всавить туда ?

Comment: А куда вам надо? Стартуйте лучше свою анимацию в разметке или используйте SwipeRefreshLayout

Comment: вот в чем дел у меня 3 таба фрагмента и на 2 табе использу. 3д тур по обьекту и там swipeRefreshLayout более чем мешает управлению поэтому надо втулбар добавить

Comment: Вы можете задизэйблить swipeRefreshLayout и он не будет реагировать на жесты

Comment: и как это сделать ????

Comment: swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false);

Comment: я эт сделал и как теперь мне  его вызвать ?он воще нереагирует)

Comment: @elik, перед запускам снова его активируйте тем же способом, потом запустите анимацию. Потом остановите анимацию, после чего обратно задизейблите. Вызов анимации может потребовать оборачивания в `View.post(new Runnable(){public void run(){//тут анимировать}})`